# How to create Excel Application Using Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, excel, netbeans

I am planning to develop a swing application for MS Excel.That Fill values in one excel sheet from another excel sheet.Manually Am doing it using by "V look up" formula. In swing application also i have to use "v look up".
Can you please help in choosing the right architecture and technologies to use with Swing. Also any good sample should be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of open source libraries which you can use to read an excel file such as [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/).

Once you've read your excel file into some data structure, this can be written into a DataModel for a JTable. Alternatively, you could write a custom DataModel which will read dynamically from the excel file, but I'd take the two steps seperately and build up the complexity once you understand the excel file reading library you choose.